# Codeigniter default routing doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

In my new CI project, I am getting the following error every time I try to access any URL other than the base url and the base url /index.php. For example, if I'd like to access the "about" page:

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL /my_base_url/about was not found on this server.

This is what my routes.php file looks like:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "base";
$route['about'] = "base/about";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

I've triple checked my Base controller and it definitely has an about method (which loads an existing "about" view).

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

And here's a few things I've set in my config.php file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/my_base_url/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The htaccess file should be in the `my_base_url` directory, and you should include a rewrite base:

```
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /my_base_url/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried this, but then got "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /my_base_url/ on this server." (I checked the permissions on that directory though, and I should be able to view it!)

Comment: @anniebabannie Are you sure `index.php` is one of the files in the `DirectoryIndex` list? Are you sure the htaccess file is actually getting read (and you have mod_rewrite loaded)?

Comment: I checked my httpd.conf file and yes, index.php is listed. I tested to see if the htaccess file was getting read by putting in gibberish (resulted in Internal Server Error – so yes it IS being read), and yes mod_rewrite is being loaded.

Comment: @anniebabannie try checking your error logs, it should give you a reason why it returned a 403 Forbidden (either can't access, or configuration disallows, etc.)

Comment: I found this "[Mon Oct 14 12:22:54 2013] [error] [client ::1] Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden" – I am not used to debugging apache server errors, where should I look to fix this?

Comment: @anniebabannie means you need to turn on follow symlinks, see the edit above

Comment: UPDATE: I went to my user .conf file, and added FollowSymLinks to Options, which seemed to work! I can now view my base url page again. Only problem is now my styles aren't loading, but that's another issue...You've helped enormously though, thank you!

Comment: @anniebabannie that sounds like a relative/absolute URI problem, try adding a `<base href="/my_base_url/">` in your page headers (or whatever the URI base should be). If your question has been answered, make sure to mark the green checkmark so your question shows up as resolved

Comment: Was having this problem and it turned out to be selinux permissions. [The fix for me was here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28589819/3585500).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache, take a look in config file.

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

AllowOverride All

Comment: Yep, both of those lines are in my httpd.conf file. I tried what Jon Lin (below) suggested but now I'm just getting "Forbidden You don't have permission to access /my_base_url/ on this server."