# PHP Write file - Permission Denied

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

I can't seem to get PHP to write to a text file on my Apache web server.

The file itself (log.txt) has an owner of "apache:apache" with access "-rw-rw-r--", its folder is owned by "apache:apache" and has permissions "drwxrwxr-x"...

Every time I tried to access log.txt, the Apache log reports "Permission Denied" on that file name.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: What PHP runtime is used? FPM typically runs as a different user.

Comment: PHP 5.4.16 (cli) when I typed "php -v".

Comment: What info do you need from phpinfo() ?

Comment: "Apache 2.0 Handler"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache permissions, PHP file create, MKDir fail](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5165183), [How to give apache permission to write to home directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22062266), [Permission denied writing to one directory, but not the other -- both have same owner/group/755](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27081132), [PHP: permission denied despite appropriate permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6941282)

Comment: iirc, apache runs as user www-data, not apache. Try changing it to that user.

Comment: I get invalid user when I do chmod for www-data. My "echo('whoami')" from a PHP file shows "apache".

Comment: I have tried ALL of those links posted by @mario and none are working. I'm still getting the same Permission Denied error :(.

Comment: Check permission on ALL the parent directories.

Comment: It was SELinux :(. Disabled it, all working now. Thanks anyway all. So all the permissions were correct but the black box being applied (SELinux) was messing things up - horrible.

Answer (score 0):

apache usually runs as user www-data:www-data not apache:apache.
Are you sure the right uid/gid?

Try writing to a new file and see who owns it

Comment: If you look at the comments, this was resolved last summer. It should have been deleted.